# Round down to nearest multiple of 10000 using PHP

Tags: php, rounding

If I have the following code which grabs an `array` of values and adds them all together, how can I then round them **down** to the nearest 10000 using PHP?

Here's the code I currently have

```
$rows = $db->get("sales");
$sales = 0;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $stock = $sales + $row['sales'];
}
return $sales;
```

An example result would be

```
146740
```

How could I then make that returned as

```
140000
```

Although if I had a number greater than **1 million**, how could I have that returned as just **1 million**?

Comment: "nearest 10 thousandth" means a fraction with 4 decimal places.

Comment: Maybe you mean "nearest multiple of 10 thousand", but your example doesn't do that. It rounds to 1 thousand, but it's not the nearest one; 147000 is closer than 146000.

Comment: @Barmar, you're correct regarding "nearest multiple of 10 thousand", but as I previously stated in my post I want to round **down**

Comment: You're still inconsistent. You say 10 thousand, but the example is 1 thousand.

Comment: Would you like to return `"1 million"` or `1000000`?

Comment: @TomFenech I'd like to return **1000000**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Divide by 10000, use `floor` to round down to an integer, then multiply by 10000:

```
$x = 146740;
$x = 10000 * floor($x/10000);
```

Or subtract the remainer:

```
$x = 146740;
$x = $x - ($x % 10000);
```

To extend this to 1 million, you can do:

```
if ($x > 1000000) {
    $divisor = 1000000;
} elseif ($x > 10000) {
    $divisor = 10000;
} else {
    $divisor = 1;
}
$x = $x - ($x % divisor);
```

Comment: Apologies, I've gone ahead and modified my question, I didn't initially realise what I was asking, my bad. I shown my example wrong.

Comment: Updated answer to use 10,000, and also show how to do it for both 1 million and 10,000.

Comment: Second example to subtract the remainder is the cleanest and fastest way - great answer

Answer (score 0):

you could divide the value by 1000. If it is integer 146740/1000 = 146. And after that multiply by 1000 will give 146000